# Как вставить счетчик liveinternet в php

Tags: php

Как вставить счетчик liveinternet в php?

Comment: [Так](http://www.php.su/forum/topic.php?forum=71&topic=8687) пробовали? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Код счётчика — это обычный javascript/html. Удобнее вставлять вне контекста php, чтобы не возиться с экранированием

```
?>
<!-- здесь счётчик -->
<?php
```

Comment: Блин, не отобразилось: ?> <!-- код счётчика --> <?php

Comment: Возможно, у автора вопроса возникли проблемы, в какой файл, а не в какое место файла вставлять счётчик. Спасибо.